# Subspaces with common images

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algorithms, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $S,T:X\to Y$ be linear transformations. Is there a method for determining all subspaces $V\subseteq X$ such that $S(V)=T(V)$ (as subspaces not necessarily pointwise). I am especially interested in the case where $\text{dim} X \geq \text{dim} Y$.

Comment: How should the general form of the answer look like? A subset of the union of Grassmannians, a finite union of parametrical descriptions of basis vectors or hyperplane equations, or some other kind? (I wonder if the second form is possible to achieve.)

Comment: Choose a basis write the linear transformations as  matrixes and find basis vectors that span these subspaces. So " finite union of parametrical descriptions of basis vectors"

Comment: Fix $W\subseteq im(S)\cap im(T)$. Then you're looking for subspaces of $S^{-1}(W)\cap T^{-1}(W)$ which are applied surjectively via both $S$ and $T$ onto $W$. This kind of reduces things to the surjective case ...

Comment: Having $S,T:U\to W$ surjective, you're looking for $V\subseteq U$ which apply via both onto W. These are the subspaces which contain complements to both kernels $V+\ker S=U$ and $V+\ker T=U$, this can be writte in terms of dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a partial and unfinished answer, when one of the transformations, say $T$, is injective. Then there exists a linear transformation $T^{-1}:T(X)\to X$ such that $T^{-1}Tx=x$ for each $x\in X$. Now let $V$ be any subspace of $X$. Then $T(V)=S(V)$ iff $S(V)\subset T(X)$ and $T^{-1}S(V)=V$. That is we have to characterize invariant subspaces $V$ of the linear transformation $T^{-1}S:S^{-1}T(X)\to X$.
All of them are subspaces of the space $Z=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (S^{-1}T)^n(X)$. So put $R=T^{-1}S|Z$.
Then $R$ is a nonsingular linear transformation on the space $Z$. According to Theorem 8 of [Gan, Chapter VII], the invariant subspaces of $R$ can be described as follows.

Let $\psi(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{n_1}\dots (\lambda-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$ be the minimal polynomial of $R$. For each natural $i\le k$ let $Z_i=\{x\in Z: (R-\lambda_kI)^{n_k}x=0\}$. Then $Z_i$ is an invariant subspace of $R$. Moreover, $Z$ splits into the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k Z_i$ of the subspaces $Z_i$ and each $R$-invariant subspace $V$ of $Z$ splits into the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k V\cap Z_i$ of the $R$-invariant subspaces $V\cap Z_i$.

So it remains to find all $R$-invariant subspaces $V$ of the subspace $Z_i$ for each natural $i\le k$.
Each such subspace splits into a sum of $R$-invariant subspaces, which are cyclic. I recall that an $R$-invariant subspace $V$ of $Z_i$ is *cyclic*, if there exists a vector $x\in V$ such that $V$ is the smallest $R$-invariant subspace of $Z_i$ containing the vector $x$. Unfortunately, I do not know a more concrete description of *all* $R$-invariant subspaces of $Z_i$.

On the other hand, when for each natural $i\le k$ the space $Z_i$ is one-dimensional (this happens, for instance, when all eigenvalues of $R$ are distinct, or, more general, when the minimal polynomial of $R$ has no multiple roots) then the $R$-invariant subspaces are exactly direct sums of families of distinct spaces $Z_i$, $i\le k$.

Concerning the general case, that is when no of the transformations $S$ and $T$ is required to be injective, we still can note that required subspace $V$ of $X$ should be contained in some subspace $Z$ of $X$. Namely, put $X_0=X$ and for each natural $n$ put $X_{n+1}=\{x\in X_n: T(x)\in S(X_n)$ and $S(x)\in T(X_n)\}$. Finlly, put $Z=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty X_n$. Since the space $X$ is finitely dimensional, the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\omega}$ stabilizes. It follows that $S(Z)=T(Z)$, that is $Z$ is the largest required subspace.

*References*

[Gan] F.R. Gantmacher, *The theory of matrices*, 2nd(?) edn., in Russian.

Comment: I beleive it is $\lambda_k I $ instead of $\lambda_k R$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "Unfortunately, I do not know a more concrete description of all R-invariant subspaces of Zi" The best description of course are blocks of the Jordan normal form. As I wrote I ams especially interested in the case where dimX≥dimY.

Comment: This is the direction I was going in before I asked the question. I think this problem is a kind of "relative" invariant subspaces problem and is similar in nature to the Jordan normal form.

Comment: @NoamKolodner I guess the blocks of the Jordan normal form correspond to the mentioned cyclic $R$-invariant subspaces.
I showed your problem to a specialist in matrix theory and he replied that the problem formulation is simple, but it is related to the problem of pairs of matrix (this is a famous unsolved problem in matrix theory, aka the wild problem). He has no answer yet, but the problem is worth to be thought about.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\chi=\dim X$ and $\gamma=\dim Y$. If $SV=TV$, let $A\in\mathbb C^{\chi\times\chi}$ be a matrix whose columns form a spanning set of $V$. Then $\operatorname{range}(SA)=SV=TV=\operatorname{range}(TA)$. Therefore $SA=TAM$ for some matrix $M\in\mathbb C^{\chi\times\chi}$.

The matrix $M$ can be chosen to be invertible: let $r=\dim SV=\dim TV$. Since $SA$ and $TA$ have the same column spaces, they admit two [rank decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) $SA=L_1R_1$ and $TA=L_2R_2$ so that $L_1,L_2\in\mathbb C^{\gamma\times r}$ have full column ranks as well as identical column spaces, and $R_1,R_2\in\mathbb C^{r\times\chi}$ have full row ranks. It follows that $L_2=L_1Q$ for some invertible matrix $Q\in GL_r(\mathbb C)$. But then $QR_2$ and $R_1$ are two matrices having the same sizes and full row ranks. Hence there exists an invertible matrix $M\in GL_\chi(\mathbb C)$ such that $R_1=QR_2M$. In turn, $SA=TAM$.

Conversely, if $SA=TAM$ for some $A\in\mathbb C^{\chi\times\chi}$ and $M\in GL_\chi(\mathbb C)$, then
$$
SV=\operatorname{range}(SA)=\operatorname{range}(TAM)=\operatorname{range}(TA)=TV
$$
where $V=\operatorname{range}(A)$. It follows that
$$
\{V: SV=TV\}
=\bigcup_{M\in GL_\chi(\mathbb C)}
\{\operatorname{range}(A): A\in\mathbb C^{\chi\times\chi},\,SA=TAM\}.
$$
This is by no means a practical parametrisation: the correspondence from $A$ to $V$ is non-injective (although it is surjective), grossly redundant and we also cannot control $\dim V=\operatorname{rank} A$.

The equation $SA=TAM$ can be vectorised as $(I_\chi\otimes S-M^\top\otimes T)\operatorname{vec}(A)=0$. When $\chi>\gamma$, given any $M\in GL_\chi(\mathbb C)$, since $I_\chi\otimes S-M^\top\otimes T$ is $\chi\gamma\times\chi\chi$, the equation always possesses a nontrivial solution $A$ (and hence a nontrivial subspace $V$ of $X$).

When $\chi=\gamma$, the situation is more delicate. If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_\gamma$ are the eigenvalues of $M$, the spectrum of $I_\chi\otimes S-M^\top\otimes T$ will be the union of the spectra of $S-\lambda_iT$ for all $i$. Therefore, given any $M$, the equation $SA=TAM$ has a nontrivial solution $A$ if and only if $S-\lambda_iT$ is singular for some $i$. If one blindly picks a random invertible matrix $M$ without solving the generalised eigenvalue problem $\det(S-\lambda T)=0$ first, the equation $SA=TAM$ will most likely admit only the trivial solution $A=0$ unless the null spaces of $S$ and $T$ has a nontrivial intersection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking for a method to describe *all* subspaces V. Your method  finds a subspace. I am unfamiliar with the vectorised notation of the equation. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @NoamKolodner For vectorisation, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). My answer here does give a method to find all subspaces $V$: just compute $A$ and $\operatorname{range}(A)$ for every invertible matrix $M$. What it doesn’t give is an *algorithm* that ends in finite steps.